# jqGrid Mouse Drag to Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-events

I'm looking for a way to trigger a resize of a jqGrid by dragging the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: in version 3.6 they've added a gridResize feature.

It adds the drag handle for you and everything.

```
jQuery("#grid")
  .jqGrid('gridResize',
      {minWidth:350, maxWidth:800, minHeight:80, maxHeight:350}
      );
```

See the demo - it's the last item under "New in version 3.6"

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: +1 as this is the "official" way. That said, the demo looks surprisingly clunky in Chrome; I hope the look & feel is improved in a future release.

Comment: this works pretty well -- except that it seems to break the collapse/expand functionality... any thoughts?

Comment: also seems really broken in opera.

Comment: That's a shame about Opera. It's a bit wonky, but I think it's good enough for me to implement. It's described as an 'experimental' feature, so hopefully it'll improve in v3.7